# Spatial join of spatialpointsframe and spatialpolygonsframe

Tags: r, join, polygon, spatial, point

I have a spatialpointsframe and spatialpolygonsframe.
I want to make a spatial join and plot the number of points per polygon(plot that show the polygons with colors).
I saw some solutions over the internet but nothing seems like the easiest way

I tried to use the SF library.

Comment: Nitzan, to find friends here, it would be good if you provide a minimal reproducible example that helps us to understand what you have done or struggle with. Could you add the specific code to your question, explain what you tried, and highlight what does not produce the expected results? As it stands right now, you pose a very generic and broad question ... so it is difficult to understand how to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.